# autocomplete function not working for mobile view

Tags: laravel

Hello  I am creating searching task in my project it works fine for destop view but when i open my website in mobile and press key then keypad is open and close within second what is problem in my code. What is mistake? why code is not working in mobile view?

//html

```
 <form class="ps-search--header" action="#" method="post">
              {{ csrf_field()}}
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Product…" id="product_name">
              <button><i class="ps-icon-search"></i></button>
              <div id="product_list"></div>
            </form>
```

//controller

```
public  function fetch(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->get('query'))
         {
              $query = $request->get('query');
              $data = DB::table('products')
                ->where('product_name', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
                ->get();
              $output = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" style=" display:block;  ;width:100%">';
                  foreach($data as $row)
                  {
                        $name=[];
                        $name=explode(" ",$row->product_name);
                       $output .= '
                       <li><a href="/productDetail/'.$row->product_slug.'">'.$row->product_name.'</a></li>
                       ';
                  }
              $output .= '</ul>';
              echo $output;
         }
    }
```

//autocomplete

```
 $('#product_name').keyup(function(){ 

        var query = $(this).val();
        if(query != '')
        {
         var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
         $.ajax({
          url:"/autocomplete",
          method:"get",
          data:{query:query, _token:_token},
          success:function(data){
           $('#product_name').fadeIn();  
                    $('#product_list').html(data);
          }
         });
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
        $('#product_name').val($(this).text());  
        $('#product_list').fadeOut();  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of `keyup` wold not work sometimes with mobile which work great on desktop
You can use this Keyup on Your autocomplete function its work on both check the code bellow

```
 $('#product_name').on('keyup input', function(e){
      
      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
      $("input").blur();
     
  }

   var query = $(this).val();
        if(query != '')
        {
         var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
         $.ajax({
          url:"/autocomplete",
          method:"get",
          data:{query:query, _token:_token},
          success:function(data){
           $('#product_name').fadeIn();  
                    $('#product_list').html(data);
          }
         });
        }
  
  
});
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
        $('#product_name').val($(this).text());  
        $('#product_list').fadeOut();  
    });
```

Comment: hello its not working plz need another solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988823/display-label-in-optgroup-and-related-value-in-option-value plz see another question